# sklearn OrdinalEncoder default ordering (categories='auto')

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science

What is the default rule used by `sklearn` `OrdinaleEcoder` to determine the order of the categories when `categories='auto'`?

Is it just sorted lexicographically? couldn't find it in the docs

Comment: Hello nivniv, did you find my answer helpful? If so, I'd appreciate if you accept it :)

Comment: Hi @DataJanitor, thanks for your reply, but this is not an exact answer, rather a "hypothesis". The straightforward assumption is for the order to be lexicographically (I also did these kind of experiments myself before posting my question..). To make sure that this is in fact the case, I would have hoped to maybe pointing to the relevant place in the scikit-learn code that does this part, or some other concrete evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, let's try it out:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import numpy as np

# Create a simple dataset
data = np.array([['Medium'], ['High'], ['Low'], ['High'], ['Medium'], ['Low']])

# Create an instance of OrdinalEncoder
encoder = OrdinalEncoder(categories='auto')

# Fit and transform the data
encoded_data = encoder.fit_transform(data)

print("Encoded Data:", encoded_data)

print("\nCategories:", encoder.categories_)

# Check if the categories are sorted alphabetically
if (np.array(np.unique(data)) == encoder.categories_[0]).all():
    print("\nThe categories are sorted alphabetically.")
# Check if the categories are sorted by the order they appear in the input data
elif (np.array([x for i, x in enumerate(data[:, 0]) if x not in data[:, 0][:i]]) == encoder.categories_[0]).all():
    print("\nThe categories are sorted by the order they appear in the input data.")
else:
    print("\nThe ordering of categories doesn't match either alphabetical or input order.")
```

Note that `np.unique()` returns the sorted unique elements of an array and is therefore suitable here.

**Output**:

```py
Encoded Data: [[2.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [2.]
 [1.]]

Categories: [array(['High', 'Low', 'Medium'], dtype='<U6')]

The categories are sorted alphabetically.
```